# How to get gid and uid in a puppet template?

Tags: puppet

What would be the correct way to get both the uid and gid for the current user the script?

I've seen the `identity` property contains the information I need, but when I try to access it in the template nothing gets returned `<%= @identity.gid %>` fails and `<%= @identity %>` is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example's syntax, I'd assume you're using ERB templating. I'd advise you to use the [EPP templating](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_template_epp.html#concept-3606) instead (and call it using the **epp()** function instead of **template()**), unless you're running Puppet 3.8 or lower (which you shouldn't either).

When you're using EPP templating language, you can use the `$facts` global variable to access its hashes, like this:

`<%= $facts[identity][gid] %>`

That would result in the gid of the user running the facter, as stated [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/core_facts.html#identity)